# Query to insert or if needed update record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
  +----------------+-----------+
  |name(varchar)PK |money(int) |
  +----------------+-----------+
```

How can i formulate a query so that it can:

1.Be able to insert a name and money value

2.If the said name already exists it should only update the money column by adding its value with that it gets from a form.
tried using:

```
   REPLACE INTO practable SET name = '$name', money = 'money' + $amount
```

It fulfills the first requirement but while updating the money column it simply replaces the old value with the new one, doesn't add them.

Here is the full code(Draft version):

```
        <?php
           //This script by another form which takes the amount and name paramters from user
    if(!empty($_GET['nameg']) && !empty($_GET['amountg'])){

        $user="root";
        $pass="password";
        $db="practice";
        $name=$_GET['nameg'];
        $amount=$_GET['amountg'];

        mysql_connect('localhost',$user,$pass) or die("Connection Failed!, " . mysql_error());
        $query="REPLACE INTO practable SET name = '$name', given = 'given' + $amount";
        mysql_select_db($db) or die("Couldn't connect to Database, " . mysql_error());
        mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query! ". mysql_error());
        mysql_close() or die("Couldn't disconnect!");



    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Did you try:
REPLACE INTO practable SET name = '$name', money = SUM(money,$amount)
By the way. Your code is extremely dangerous! It allows for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Please read up on SQL-injection... See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: I know, it's the draft version :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `insert ... on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO practable(name,money) VALUES('$name',$amount) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 name = '$name', money = `money` + $amount
```

I assume your variables `$name` and `$amount` are properly escaped

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

From the documentation:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try leaving out the '' on money. That will keep it as a colmmn and not as a string

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query="REPLACE INTO practable SET name = '$name', given = given+" . (int)$amount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace will delete the old row if the primary key exists so you are adding to nothing.